# how to pass object key to function using datalist

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a searchable dropdown using datalist in angular js. datalist is bonded to the input box and after selecting option one change event occurs that need a key from the object. But I am unable to pass object key

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="selectedSkill" 
       ng-change="show(selectedName,selectedSkill)" 
       placeholder="Select skill" 
       list="skill-list"/>

<datalist id="skill-list">
         <option ng-repeat="s in skillObject">
           {{s.value}}
         </option>
</datalist>
```

I have to pass selectedSkill as key, not as a value in ng-change.
it is possible with
ng-options="skill.key as skill.value for skill in skillObject"

I have googled all about how to pass key value using ng-repeat but not succeed in that.

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="selectedSkill" 
       ng-change="show(selectedName,selectedSkill)" 
       placeholder="Select skill" 
       list="skill-list"/>

<datalist id="skill-list">
         <option ng-repeat="s in skillObject">
           {{s.value}}
         </option>
</datalist>
```

I have to select or search value using the input box so all operation will be using input box only.

PFB skillObject looks like :

```
skillObject=[
{"key":1
 "value":"java"
},
{"key":2
 "value":"javascript"
},
{"key":3
 "value":"angular"
},
]
```

Comment: this doesn't make any sense - you only get a value back from a datalist option - which you have defined as `s.value` 
you should show how the `skillObject` does look like - because i think you are on the wrong track here

Comment: skillObject=[
{"key":1
 "value":"java"
},
{"key":2
 "value":"javascript"
},
{"key":3
 "value":"angular"
},
]

Comment: I have to pass key only to function as parameter but dropdown should show the value

Comment: you do realize that you don't have to choose a value from a datalist - instead you can input any value in your text box - so why do you even use a datalist if you need a key ? beside the fact you don't necessary need the key - you can iterate over the skillObject array and search for the value

Comment: Actually, my requirement is to create a searchable dropdown and controller function take a parameter as key only  from skillObject and dropdown should only show the value from skillObject

Comment: as i already said - you can't achieve that goal with a datalist - you should probably take a 3rd party solution - something like https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/#examples should work without any troubles